# representation for a pole of order N

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, meromorphic-functions

If a meromorphic function has a single pole of order $N$ at $z_0$, then is the principal part of that function always

$$\frac{c}{(z-z_0)^N}$$ for some constant $c$? A counterexample or proof would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, of course not. Take$$\frac1{z^2}+\frac1z\tag1$$(with domain equal to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$) for instance. The principal part of this function is $(1)$.

Comment: Seems obvious now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, the principal part will be
$$
\frac{c_N}{(z-z_0)^N}+\frac{c_{N-1}}{(z-z_0)^{N-1}}+\dots+\frac{c_1}{z-z_0}.
$$